# Find the Maclaurin series representation of the function: $\ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x})$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

Find the Maclaurin series representation of the function: $\ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x})$ I know the answer, but i want to know why my approch did not work.

I started with the series
$$\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}x^n $$
then i put in $x=\frac{2x}{1-x}$ and get:
$$\ln(1+x)=\ln(1+\frac{2x}{1-x})=\ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x}))=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}(\frac{2x}{x-1})^n$$
It seems like this is not correct based on wolfam alpha. Where did i make a mistake?

Comment: That's not a Maclaurin series.

Comment: Hint: $\ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x}) = \ln(1+x) - \ln(1-x)$

Comment: alright, i see. thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is not formally incorrect (although you would have to define in what sense the series converges), it is simply not a Maclaurin series. A Maclaurin series is expressed in powers of $x$ with constant coefficients, here you express it in inverse powers of $1-x$ which is not the form of the series. You could try to expand each function $\left(\frac{2x}{x-1}\right)^n$ but that is unnecessarily complicated and dangerous.
Much simpler, write $\ln \left( \frac{1+x}{1-x} \right)=\ln (1+x)-\ln (1-x)$, develop each function separately and check which terms cancel out to find the answer. I will let you conclude!

Comment: i see. the thing that confused me the most is that wolfram alpha says the series converges/(is equal to) to $\ln(\frac{3x-1}{x-1})$.

Comment: I'm sorry to be so mean but that is totally incorrect, compositions don't work just like that. Sorry. On the other hand, linear combinations do work just fine so the substraction attempt will yield a correct result.